# Load 3d objects for physcis simulations

Tags: c++, 3d, simulation, physics

I'm a physics student and my field of interest is fluid simulations. In the research group where I belong, the main method we use is the Lattice Bolztmann method for solving the Navier-Stokes equations. It is based in the discretization of space and time, dividing the space into a lattice.

One important thing in this model is the properties of the simulation space, I mean, whether at certain point there is an obstacle, a fan or other thing.

So far, we can define our simulation space in a traditional C++ array and "by hand" assigning properties to certain points (something like `L[ix][iy][iz] = fan;` and the simulation well take this into account while doing the calculations). This is really limited because we can use only simple shapes as obstacles or sources. I would like to implement some method to load complex arrays and see what happens in the fluid.

PD: I'm kind of asking for a way to convert a 3d model into a 3d C++ array where if there is an object you put a 1 and if there is no object a 0, something like that...

Comment: You wish to convert "a 3d model" into a 3d array of cells, where each cell contains a number. What is the model? An equation that describes a surface? Can you give us a simple example? (You can reply in a comment.)

Comment: You can store your array in a file and parse the file using `cin >>` or `fscanf()`.

Comment: In the LB model, the space and time are discrete. Each space point is a lattice, and each lattice has a set of discrete velocities and distribution functions, each time step, those functions are calculated based in some evolution rule. The point is that de cells can be of different types, cells of "air" in wich the velocity of the fluid is given by de distribution functions, obscacule cells in which the velocity is always cero, or fan cells, de velocity field has some fixed values. and the system is cartesian ( de cells are boxes of a certain length) .

Comment: The question is there is a way to took a 3d model (blender models) and use the geometric information for my simulation? thanks